# websocket send(message) in quick succession to C websocket server (open_ssl, posix)

Tags: javascript, c, websocket, openssl

i've written a websocket server using C, posix and open_ssl. testing from a simple javascript client i send a burst of messages like this;

```
  for(var x =0; x<2000; x++){
        ws.send("burst:"+x+" bufferedamount:"+ ws.bufferedAmount);
  }
```

the server handles this up to a point (x ~1200) then SSL_pending>0 and SSL_read  reads the entire buffer size (1024), NOT the correct 37 bytes.

SSL_pending>0 means more reads are required, which i do in a loop until SSL_pending==0, see output below;

```
payload_len:31
-->thread_id:-797378816, sock_fd:5, listening<--
-->thread_id:-797378816, sock_fd 5, SSL_read:SSL_ERROR_NONE:37

payload_len:31
-->thread_id:-797378816, sock_fd:5, listening<--
-->thread_id:-797378816, sock_fd 5, SSL_read:SSL_ERROR_NONE:1024
-------------------->SSL_pending:15360
-------------------->SSL_pending:14336
-------------------->SSL_pending:13312
-------------------->SSL_pending:12288
-------------------->SSL_pending:11264
-------------------->SSL_pending:10240
-------------------->SSL_pending:9216
-------------------->SSL_pending:8192
-------------------->SSL_pending:7168
-------------------->SSL_pending:6144
-------------------->SSL_pending:5120
-------------------->SSL_pending:4096
-------------------->SSL_pending:3072
-------------------->SSL_pending:2048
-------------------->SSL_pending:1024
-------------------->SSL_pending:0
```

the first SSL_pending = 15360 (around the maximum record size of 16kB for SSLv3/TLSv1, which appears to make sense). what i don't understand is why the server starts to read the entire buffer (1024) at a point. stack overflow??? it's like remaining websocket frames have been joined and sent together. i haven't tried but was thinking about joining all the SSL_pending reads then trying to read it?

if i send a burst like this the server has no issue

```
setInterval(function() { ws.send("burst: bufferedamount:"+ ws.bufferedAmount); }, 0);
```

Comment: What is your question or questions?

Comment: if i send a 30byte message, the server should read a 30byte message. when i do it quickly enough ssl_pending hits 16kb and the 30byte ssl_read becomes a 1024byte (buffer size) read. question: is the underlying communication joining the 30bytes together (up to 16kb) then sending?

Comment: i have printf the 1024byte ssl_read in binary, i can see the websocket frames have been joined (binary pattern repeats). i think i understand now, i need to ssl_read until ssl_pending==0 (then the ssl record will decode properly), then loop through the output and decode the websocket frames as normal.